# IF URL do pre-defined function

Tags: jquery

I've previously created a function:

```
function testfunction(){
    alert('test function');
}
```

And later called it by using an onClick event:

```
$(".test-submit").click(testfunction);
```

All that works fine, but I now need to call the function again if the page is equal to a word e.g.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?launchfunction") > -1) {
//    testfunction NEEDS TO LAUNCH HERE
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: So why don't you just call it?

Comment: Call the function.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Had no idea you could directly call functions e.g. testfunction(); Assumed they had to be targeted at selectors.

Comment: As you are using `jQuery` put all of the functions that you require to fire on page load like this* -> `$(function(){ testfunction(); })` *Other methods are available.

Answer (score 1):

```
function testfunction(){
    alert('test function');
}

if(window.location.href.indexOf("?launchfunction") > -1) {
    testfunction();
}
```